# How to integrate a COMET chat in a PHP application

Tags: php, javascript, chat, comet

I'm thinking of integrating a chat inside an already written and working php application.
As I have to choose the chat implementation yet I'll show you some consideration:

1. PHP is not good for Comet application. A php comet server for managing chat would not scale well, so it wouldn't be my first choice.
2. Node.js + Socket I/O, can eventually be a good option for the chat engine.
3. AMQP (RabbitMQ?) can be another possibly good solution, not exclusive with node.js as they can integrate pretty well.

The main problem is: how can I avoid code and business  logic duplication? There are some aspects I'd like to point out:

- The application manages users in a RBAC fashion. Users should be able to chat with other users depending on their role (and some other business logics). It would be hard (and bad practice imo) to duplicate that logic.
- If I use two different server processes (as I think) for IM and application, how can I manage http session?

In short: IM would be tightly coupled with business logic, so I really need to avoid code/logic duplication, but at the same time I don't want a PHP chat engine.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you make it a little clearer as to what exactly it is that you are asking?

Comment: sorry, i tried to remove some stuff. Anyway, suppose my application is facebook, and it's running in PHP. How can i add (comet) chat support without rewriting business logic? (who am I? am I logged in, is Jhonny my friend - and can I chat with him? and so on...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using something in my php application called `Pusher`

Here is the Link for [Pusher](http://pusher.com/)

Comment: Actually, it seems a possible solution, but I strongly prefer an in-house software :) for commercial reason mainly

Comment: @ArtoAle have you looked into server-sent-events or websockets?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding well :)
My problem is not how to implement reverse ajax (socket I/O provides a great websockets wrappers wich falls back in other reverse ajax solution that work pretty well). My concern is: if I have a PHP driven application, with lot of user management logic in it, how can I avoid rewriting those logic for managing the chat sistem?)